# Github new Branch creation restriction

Tags: git, github

I was wondering if there is anyway to restrict the branch creation in GitHub. I have 4-5 branches created for a repo and would like to maintain it that way. I have applied branch restriction rules on my master branch and hence the developers cannot merge into master but they can create their own branches . Is there a way i can restrict and force developers to use the other branches that are available and not create a new one ?

Note: I use GITHUB Enterprise

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Github Enterprise this is available since version 3.7.0 (2022-10-25):
https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/release-notes#repositories

For public Github this is supported since May 2022.
See:

> ### Block creation of branches that have matching names
>
> **Now, admins can block creation of branches that match a configured name pattern**.
>
> For example, if a repository's default branch is renamed from `master` to `main`, admins can prevent any subsequent creation or push of the `master` branch so that only the new branch name is used.
>
> Previously, admins could use branch protection rules to restrict who could push to existing branches, but they couldn't block the creation of those branches.
> This is now possible using a branch protection setting named `Restrict pushes that create matching branches`.
> To use the setting, create a new branch protection rule with a name pattern that matches the branch name you want to block (e.g. master or not-allowed*). Then, enable the settings Restrict who can push to matching branches and Restrict pushes that create matching branches, as shown here:
>
> [image: An image showing the two branch protection settings to enable for restricting pushes that create matching branches -- https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1767415/166982191-bb0af50c-971a-481c-ae80-a17ef91223c3.png?ssl=1]
>
> For more information, visit About protected branches in the GitHub documentation.
>
> We appreciate feedback on this and other topics in GitHub's public feedback discussions.

In your case, adding a rule '`*`' will prevent the creation of *any* new branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block creating branches on a repo (I mean not locally).
You can achieve it by adding a `pre-push` git hook from client side to block publishing of branches. But the problem is that every git user have to add it locally and can omit it by simply passing `--no-verify` to push command.

But it you prefer server-side solution you can create a `pre-receive` hook on repo to block pushing to non-existing branches.
Creating a new remote branch is also a push operation.

And it works also for Github Enterprise as I'm also using it.
You can read more here about git hooks in git documentation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such option to **Restrict branch creation**. Branch is a basic necessity of `git` and therefore everyone is eligible to create a  new branch. But certainly, like you said, you can protect some defined set of branches for `commits` and `merge` .